# how to create a filter to filter ng-model value in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a input field:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="defaultValue">
```

In my controller it is a empty string:

```
$scope.defaultValue = "";
```

I want to create a filter to compare the value in an object like:

```
   items: [
    {
    repo_status: null,
    cyberridge_loan_number: "FH00-0012-0003-0012",
    repo_id: 18,
    cr_loan_status: "CLOSED",
    eff_days_delinquent: null,
    principal_balance: null,
    preemptive_charge_off_balance: 0,
    total_final_charge_off_balance: 0
    },
    ...
]
```

for example: compare if the repo_id > 18? I have created a ng-repeat:

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.items[0]">{{value}}</li>
```

(because this ng-repeat is for all same format api, I used {key, value} pair)

But how to make a logic filter like (repo_id > 18 ?) and apply to ng-repeat?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom filter like this,

```
 $scope.greaterThan = function(prop, val) {
      return function(item) {
        if (item[prop] > val) return true;
      }
    }
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])

app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.defaultValue  = 0;
    
    $scope.items = [{
      repo_status: null,
      cyberridge_loan_number: "FH00-0012-0003-0012",
      repo_id: 18,
      cr_loan_status: "CLOSED",
      eff_days_delinquent: null,
      principal_balance: null,
      preemptive_charge_off_balance: 0,
      total_final_charge_off_balance: 0
    },
    {
      repo_status: null,
      cyberridge_loan_number: "FH00-0012-0003-0012",
      repo_id: 34,
      cr_loan_status: "OPEN",
      eff_days_delinquent: null,
      principal_balance: null,
      preemptive_charge_off_balance: 0,
      total_final_charge_off_balance: 0
    }];
    
    $scope.greaterThan = function(prop, val) {
      return function(item) {
        if (item[prop] > val) return true;
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <input type="text" ng-model="defaultValue">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter: greaterThan('repo_id', defaultValue)">         {{item}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!